# Why doesn't this snippet of code print the number normally?

Tags: c++

Why do I get two different results? Unsigned long is big enough to handle such number, and it can't be an overflow of some kind, right?

I am deliberately trying to make it show in decimal form, but it just doesn't work.

What could be the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Print(unsigned long num)
{
    cout<<dec<<num<<endl;
}
int main() 
{
    Print(9110865112);  
    cout<<dec<<9110865112;
    return 0;
}
```

### Edit

It outputs:

```
520930520
9110865112
```

Comment: "unsigned long is big enough to handle such number" - why do you think that? `long` is often 32 bits, and your number needs at least 34.

Comment: See, for example, here - for many environments, your number is greater than `ULONG_MAX`: https://ideone.com/6eFc9J

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad, I made a mistake, i though int is 4 and long is 8 bytes long!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`unsigned long` is not always sufficiently large. With 32 bits it can occupy integers from 0 up to and including 2<sup>32</sup>-1, which is about four billions. `9'110'865'112` is nine billions and would thus not fit into `unsigned long`.

Try outputting `sizeof unsigned long` and see what you get.

Also, consider your output: `9110865112` mod 2<sup>32</sup> is `520930520`, which basically proves that `unsigned long` is 32 bit large on your machine.

Comment: English [billion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,000,000,000) = e.g. Norwegian milliard, FTFY.

Comment: American billion = French/Italian/German milliard.  British use was milliard to, until very recently.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah, sorry for that. I'm German and overly used to Milliarde.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's still not universally "standardised" to deem "billion" as 1,000,000,000 in the UK, though for formal/legal/financial use, sadly, it is so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with your "sadly".  My first contact with the British was in the early 1970's, when milliard was by far the most common use; today, my contact is largely in more "technologically advanced" milieu, where the American "billion" is almost universal.  (Of course, in France and Germany, where I've worked most, it's still "milliard".)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the numeric literal that you specify is too large to fit in an unsigned long.

When you use the literal directly, the compiler treats it as `long long`, and chooses the proper overload for `operator <<`.

To fix this problem, use `unsigned long long` in the signature of the `Print` function:

```
void Print(unsigned long long num)
{
    cout<<dec<<num<<endl;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/pmHAsl)

Answer (score 1):

Because 9,110,865,112 is greater than 32 bits, the method is only accepting 32 of the bits even though you're trying to pass it more.

To fix this, you should use an `unsigned long long` data type for you `num` parameter. When you print it directly written as a constant, the code prints out find because the compiler says that constant is an `unsigned long long`, but when you pass it as an `unsigned long`, the compiler says that constant should be an `unsigned long`. Because it's not an `unsigned long`, it drops some of the bits. (I'm suprised your compiler didn't print out a warning.)

As a reference, an `unsigned long` can hold values between 0 and 4,294,967,295 (inclusive). Any value great than this should be assigned a larger data type. An `unsigned long long` can hold values between 0 and 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (inclusive).

It is worth noting that frequently the data types `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` are used in place of `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` respectively. The `u` denotes that the number is unsigned (if the `u` is left out, the number is assumed to be signed). The number (`64` and `32` in this case) states how many bytes the number should have. And `_t` at the end just indicates that this is a data type. So `(u)int#_t` is a common way to write numeric data types; `#` can be 8, 16, 32, or 64 in standard C++ depending on the number of bits you need.

To summarize: You're throwing a number that's too large at the function. You need to change your function's parameters to support this number:

```
void Print(uint64_t num){
    cout << dec << num << endl;
}
```